# Multiple subnets in same AZ with eksctl

Tags: amazon-eks, eksctl

In the eksctl ClusterConfig file, how to map if I have multiple subnets (subnets with different CIDR range) in the same AZ ?

```
  eu-west-1a:
      id: "subnet-02a3dacfd211d0870"
      cidr: "192.168.32.0/22"
  eu-west-1b:
      id: "subnet-07a7b2710e102cc03"
      cidr: "192.168.36.0/22"
  eu-west-1c:
      id: "subnet-00b560c1f99779a6d"
      cidr: "192.168.40.0/22"
  eu-west-1a:
      id: "subnet-0c5e28e892372ebf4"
      cidr: "192.168.47.0/25"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a discussion on eksctl's slack channel, multiples subnets per AZ is not supported yet. From the discussion:

> isn't supported currently because that field takes a map which does not permit duplicate keys (availability zones here)

There are some request for this also:

https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/475#issuecomment-498995479
https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/806

Answer (score 1):

this is supported by `eksctl` since version 0.32.0:

> eksctl version 0.32.0 introduced further subnet topology customisation with the ability to:
>
> - List multiple subnets per AZ in VPC configuration

https://eksctl.io/usage/vpc-networking/#custom-subnet-topology